# proper escaping for tsch programmable tab completion

Tags: escaping, csh, tcsh, tab-completion

I'm trying to configure programmable tab completion for a certain command alias:
when hitting tab after command `notes` i want the shell to complete from existing file names under specific path `~/notes/notes_db/{some,files,here}`

in my .cshrc.user file i have set up the following `complete` declaration:

```
complete note 'p/1/`ls ~/notes/notes_db/`/'
```

alas when I test this by typing `note [TAB]`, tcshell responds with:

> note [TAB] Unmatched `.

I tried various forms of escaping the ls command within the backtics 
but non of my attempts worked.

please, can anyone explain how should i properly escape this declaration?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are (at least) two problems:

1. the output of `ls` contains slashes (`/`), which clash with the syntax of the `complete` command. To bypass, use a different separator, e.g. `@`
2. `~` is not replaced when appearing inside single quotes. Use `$HOME` instead.
3. (just guessing) if by any chance you have `ls` defined to be some alias (very common), inside your `complete` you'd want the unaliased `ls`. So use `\ls`.

We get:

```
complete note 'p@1@`\ls $HOME/notes/notes_db`@'
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
(it was option 1 btw)